# Get image file size from response headers with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, filesize

I want to get the file size of an image with jQuery.

Its almost there but i seem to keep on getting an error on one line
Can anyone help me out :)

This is the full script that does all the magic. Heres a jsfiddle of it

http://jsfiddle.net/UmUvC/

```
function displayVals() {
    var original = jQuery("#single").val();
    jQuery(".origimg").attr("src", original);
    var width = jQuery(".origimg").width();
    jQuery(".origprev").attr("style", "background: url(" + original + ") no-repeat 0 0 / 100% auto transparent");
    jQuery("p").delay(2000).queue(function() {
        jQuery(this).html("http://src.sencha.io/" + width + "/" + original);
        jQuery(".theimg").attr("src", "http://src.sencha.io/" + width + "/" + original);

        function getImageSizeInBytes(original) {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("HEAD", original, false);
            request.send(null);
            var headerText = request.getAllResponseHeaders();
            var re = /Content\-Length\s*:\s*(\d+)/i;
            re.exec(headerText);
            return parseInt(RegExp.$1);
        }
        var size_image = getImageSizeInBytes(original);
        jQuery('.size').html(size_image);
    })
}
jQuery('.go').click(

function() {
    displayVals();
    var original = jQuery("#single").val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The same origin policy doesn't allow resources to be requested from a domain different than the one making the request. For e.g., a script located on jsfiddle.net cannot '`XMLHttpRequest`' a resource located on *src.sencha.io*. Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) allows for accessing resources located on different domains if the server sends this header: **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: your-domain.com**

In your JSFiddle demo, requesting for http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png or /favicon.png works. This is because fiddle.jshell.net allows CORS for jsfiddle.net.

[image]

Try requesting with any other URL and look at your console. It should report: Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Do you know of any way in which jQuery can get the file size of a image? Where it will work more reliably

Comment: jQuery/Ajax alone cannot help. If you have control over the server-side code, send a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with '*'. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`